# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to disable all form elements by a div, so I tried as following:

```
var form  = elt.find("form:first-child");
// Disable all form elements
form.css('display','relative');
var lightBox = $('div');
lightBox.css({
    'display': 'absolute',
    'top': '0',
    'right': '0',
    'bottom': '0',
    'left': '0'
});
form.append(lightBox);
```

But I get this error message:

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': The new child element
>   contains the parent.

How can I solve this?

Comment: `$('div')` is very unlikely to be what you want.

Comment: Do you want to add a new div as the lightbox? `var lightBox = $('div');` this currently selects all divs in the document. Do you mean `var lightBox = $('<div>');` ?

Answer (score 4):

`$('div')` selects all divs. If you want to create a div, you should use `$('<div>')` instead.

```
var form  = elt.find("form:first-child");
// Disable all form elements
form.css('display','relative');
var lightBox = $('<div>');
lightBox.css({
    'display': 'absolute',
    'top': '0',
    'right': '0',
    'bottom': '0',
    'left': '0'
});
form.append(lightBox);
```